# Finding the coefficients in a vector space of numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, vector-spaces, algebraic-number-theory

Consider the vector space $V=\operatorname{span}_{\mathbb Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt 3)$ of all rational linear combinations of $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 3$ over $\mathbb Q$. If it makes things easier, take the module $\operatorname{span}_{\mathbb Z}(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)$.

My question is:

> Given $\alpha = a\sqrt 2+b\sqrt 3$, how can we express the coefficients $a$ and $b$ in terms of $\alpha$?

Clearly by a simple linear algebra argument, the coefficients are uniquely determined for any $\alpha \in V$, but it's not obvious how to determine them given access to $\alpha$ alone (e.g. say we have access to arbitrarily many decimal digits $d_i\in\{0,\dots,9\}$ such that $\alpha = \sum_{i\in\mathbb Z}10^id_i$).

I suppose one can find them if we can define an inner product on $V$, but its not obvious how to define an inner product explicitly in terms of $\alpha$. For instance, I can easily define
$$\langle a\sqrt2+b\sqrt3,c\sqrt2+d\sqrt3\rangle = ac+bd,$$
and then we would get $a=\langle \alpha,\sqrt2\rangle$ and $b=\langle\alpha,\sqrt 3\rangle$, but obviously this is cheating.

I've tried messing around with different combinations of $\alpha$, $\alpha^2$, etc., but I can't seem to get anywhere. I appreciate any help with this.

---

#### Disclaimer

I suspect this is impossible, because it feels like if it were possible, then we could use something similar to express $\mathfrak{Re}(z)$ in terms of $z$ alone (without using $\bar z$ or anything like that), and I suspect that if *that* were possible, I would surely have come across it somewhere.

If it is impossible, a proof of impossibility would be nice, though I have no idea how one would go about such a thing.

Comment: Numbers of the form $a\sqrt2+b\sqrt3$ are dense in the reals, so no finite number of decimal places of $\alpha$ will be enough to get you $a$ and $b$. On the other hand, there are integer-relation finding algorithms that will find you $a$ and $b$ that make $a\sqrt2+b\sqrt3$ agree with $\alpha$ to any given number of decimal places.

Comment: You need to be more specific with what do you mean "in terms of".
What kind of functions are allowed?
If you allow only basic algebraic operations, it is indeed impossible.

Comment: @jjagmath why? Is there a proof of this?

Comment: The impossibility is shown by the following. Consider numbers of the form
$$s_m=(\sqrt3-\sqrt2)^m$$ with $m>0$ and **odd** positive integer. The binomial formula then tells us that $s_m$ is of the form $a\sqrt2+b\sqrt3$ for some integers $a,b$ (depending on $m$, of course). But for a large $m$ we can make $s_m$ as close to zero as we wish. For example with $m=21$ we get
$$s_{21}=8205571449 \sqrt{3}-10049731549 \sqrt{2}.$$
Here $s_{21}\approx3.518\cdot10^{-11}$ so you need more than ten decimals to distinguish it from  $a=b=0$.

Comment: (cont'd) Here $s_m\to0$ as $m\to\infty$ (because $|\sqrt3-\sqrt2|<1/2$), so for larger $m$ you need more and more decimals to tell it from zero. So to have any hope, you need an upper bound on $|a|$ and $|b|$. Then you have a finite (but infeasible) search. You can make that search feasible by for example the method in the answer (or some other method Gerry may know about but I don'r).

Comment: Hmm. That's actually a bad example on "impossibility" because if $s_m=a\sqrt3-b\sqrt2$ then $1/s_m=a\sqrt3+b\sqrt2$, and we can solve for $a$ and $b$ if we can calculate $s_m\pm 1/s_m$, which is not too difficult. You should only look at this example as giving an idea of the precision needed

Comment: It is true that "lots" (infinitely many) $a$ and $b$ will give $\left|\alpha-\left(a\sqrt2+b\sqrt3\right)\right|<\varepsilon$ for any precision $\varepsilon,$ but if we ask for "small" $a$ and $b,$ this is more doable, as mentioned by Gerry Myerson.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb Z}\newcommand{floor}[1]{\left\lfloor#1\right\rfloor}$As alluded to by Gerry Myerson, there are algorithms which take algebraic integers like $\alpha=a\sqrt2+b\sqrt3$ of arbitrary (say, decimal) precision and can output good (and small) $a,b\in\ZZ$ which approximate $\alpha.$

Even stronger, there are algorithms which can produce minimal polynomials: given a good enough approximation of a real number $\alpha$ which is the root of a polynomial $p(x)\in\ZZ[x]$ and given the degree $d:=\deg p,$ we can provide a good $p(x).$ Plugging in your $\alpha$ with $d=4$ into the algorithm would do what you want.

I will outline one way to do this. The idea is to use [lattice basis reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_reduction). Pick some very large integer $N$ representing precision of $\alpha$ and consider the set of $d$ vectors
$$\left\langle 1, 0, \cdots, 0, \floor{N\alpha^0}\right\rangle, \\
\left\langle 0, 1, \cdots, 0, \floor{N\alpha^1}\right\rangle, \\
\vdots \\
\left\langle 0, 0, \cdots, 1, \floor{N\alpha^{d-1}}\right\rangle.$$
These vectors define a lattice in $\mathbb R^{d+1}.$ After lattice basis reduction (say, with [Lenstra–Lenstra–Lovász](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm#Applications)), we will have small vectors like
$$v=\left\langle a_0,a_1,\cdots,a_d,\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}a_k\floor{N\alpha^k}\right\rangle.$$
If the last component of $v$ is small enough, then we guess that it's supposed to be $0$ if we replaced the approximations $\floor{N\alpha^k}$ with actual $\alpha^k$s. In other words, we hope
$$\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}a_k\alpha^k=0.$$
Thus, we can read the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ straight off the other coefficients $a_0,\ldots,a_d$ of $v.$